# Why am I getting a FileNotFoundError when trying to create a SparkContext?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently on Python: 3.7.9, spark: spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2

In this project venv, I have the settings as:

```
kafka-python 2.0.2
pip 21.2.4
py4j 0.10.9
pyspark 2.4.6
setuptools 57.4.0
```

System environment variables:

```
SPARK_HOME         C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2
PYTHONPATH         %SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%
PATH               %SPARK_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\python;%PATH%
```

I am trying to execute following code in Python:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingReceiverKafkaWordCount")
```

I get this in Console:

```
C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\kafka_consumer.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\kafka_consumer.py", line 7, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingReceiverKafkaWordCount")
  File "C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 101, in _launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, env=env)
  File "C:\Users\MANU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\MANU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In case it's required: my dir structure is: C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\spark\python...

Comment: Do you have java installed? What version? Also, Spark doesn't use kafka-python so you should remove that

Comment: I have both java 8 and 15 on my pc. My JAVA_HOME is set to: C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_261                                                                                                                                         
But my PyCharm IDE on terminal shows: (venv) C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1>java --version                                 java 15.0.1 2020-10-20 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I was creating KafkaConsumer, but SparkContext itself gives errror.

Comment: Even if I remove kafka-python and remove from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils, I still get the same error.

Comment: The fact that the traceback includes java_gateway and a subprocess module call, it's definitely not a Kafka issue and is certainly only related to Java. Plus, you've only declared a Spark context variable and never really use it... Spark doesn't support Java 15, last I checked, and you should not be using pyspark 2.4.6 with Spark 3... Besides, if the goal is simply to consume Kafka data from Python, you don't need Spark or Java since you would use the kafka-python library, for example, instead

Comment: Thanks a lot! My Sparkhome was set to 3.1.2 and my pyspark in project venv was 2.4.6. So I changed Sparkhome to 2.4.6, since pyspark.streaming.kafka required pyspark 2.4.6. It worked. And I am applying Spark Streaming on Kafka data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information provided, you've installed pyspark separately from your Spark installation, which means you're going to have version issues

You should run Spark submit / pyspark shell directly from your Spark folder to ensure its the same versions.

Similarly download the correct spark-sql-kafka-0-10 version jar for your code

Comment: I got this solved for now and encountered some other error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69064901/getting-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes-on-spark-submit