# Getting File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load on spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently on Python: 3.7.9, spark: spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6

In this project venv, I have the settings as:

```
kafka-python 2.0.2
pip 21.2.4
py4j 0.10.9
pyspark 2.4.6
setuptools 57.4.0
```

System environment variables:

```
SPARK_HOME         C:\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6
PYTHONPATH         %SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%
PATH               %SPARK_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\python;%PATH%
JAVA_HOME          C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261
```

I am trying to spark-submit following code in Python:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
```

kafka_consumer.py is located in C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1

```
Command I ran: (venv) C:\Users\MANU\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1>spark-submit  kafka_consumer.py
```

I get this in Console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MANU/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/kafka_consumer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 72, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: it looks like you have Python 3.8 somewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700384/how-to-fix-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes-error-when-tryin. And what is the reason to use Spark 2.4?

Comment: For this code, I installed Python 3.7.9. My Pycharm python interpreter is set to 3.7.9. Since I had to use pyspark.streaming.kafka, which requires pyspark 2.4.6. So I had to set SPARK_HOME to spark 2.4.6, else it gives FileNotFoundError. I have python 3.9 and python 3.7 on my pc.

Comment: Spark Streaming does not require 2.4.6... Use the correct "Kafka-0_10" module, which is available in latest Spark 3

Comment: As I find, Kafka-0_10 is not available for python: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html                                https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: When I use Spark3.1.2, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka'. So I use spark 2.4.6 as given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053460/no-module-named-pyspark-streaming-kafka-even-with-older-spark-version

Comment: It was cloudpickle.py problem. Got the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348860/spark-installation-problems-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes

Comment: Just ensure that you grants all users the permission to run the file launcher python file (app.py or main.py or whatever the launcher is) before you actually run it. 

$ chmod a+x API.py 
$ python API.py